# Pass argument to twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have in twig:

```
{% for entry in blog_entries %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and in Entity:

```
public function getTitle($prefix) {
   return $prefix . $this->title;
}
```

How can i pass variable in this example?

```
<h2>{{ entry.title(test) }}</h2>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If test is a variable, your example is perfectly valid. If, however, it is a string, you need to pass it as a string:

```
{{ entry.getTitle('test') }}
```

or

```
{{ entry.title('test') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return just one variable, and I think you need a spce between the prefix and the title? Try this one:

```
public function getTitle($prefix) {
   $return = $prefix . " " . $this->title;
   return $return;
}
```

Hope this works, if not just leave a comment and I'll look into it again.